# Embed SWF file in PDF programmatically

Tags: java, php, .net, pdf-generation, pdf-conversion

I need to embed SWF file content in PDF format and need to do it programmatically. I found iText library to do this task, but it is not open source. If anybody knows some open source library to do this task, then please let me know.

Comment: *"..but it is not open source"*  Why is that important to you?  Are you confusing 'open source' with 'free'?  They are two separate things.

Comment: iText *is* open source, and it can be used as is in likely-minded open source projects. What you seem to want is a library, either closed or open source, with a license to use it in a closed source project. Thus, you should have posted your licensing requirements. That been said, library recommendations are off-topic on SO.

Comment: Thanks for reply and sorry for confusion. Yes, I want 'free' library to include in my commercial project for embedding  SWF file in the PDF document.